# How to get total minutes to display as Xhrs, Xmin?

Tags: php, math, time

I'm taking a total number of minutes and am trying to calculate total hrs & minutes.

If you do:

```
$elapsed = "6476"; // Trying to get 107:56 (107 hours, 56 min)

if ($elapsed > 60) { $format = "i:s"; }
if ($elapsed > 3600) { $format = "H:i:s"; } 

$showdiff = gmdate($format, $elapsed);
```

The problem with this is it doesn't work for calculations above 23hrs 59min.

So, you can do simple division:

```
$elapsed = $elapsed / 60; // total hours
```

Only then you will get a fraction (in this case, 107.933333333). I need to keep this as hours and minutes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to show zeros (i.e. 0 hours or 0 mins) or strip them from the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use division (as you've stated) and modulus division to accomplish what you want.

```
$hours = floor($elapsed / 60);
$minutes = round(($elapsed / 60) % 60);

echo $hours . "hrs " . $minutes . "min";
```

Comment: Could this be expanded to seconds?

Comment: Change `$minutes` to `$minutes = floor(($elapsed / 60) % 60)` and add `$seconds = round($elapsed / (3600)) % 60);`.  Note that your initial input of 6476 is in minutes, so you will have to change this value to seconds for this to work.  The `3600` comes from 60 seconds per minute * 60 minutes per hour.

Comment: One last thing... I noticed if the minutes are an even number (ie 72 even hours), the seconds get messed up because the minutes returns a single 0 instead of 00. I tried adding a ,2 at the end of minutes round but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

you could try

```
$elapsed = $elapsed / 60; // total hours (107.933333333)
$parts = explode(".", $elapsed); // split 107.93333 into 2 parts using the . as a separator
$minutes = $parts[1] // $parts[0] is 107, this will be the .9333
$minutes = $minutes * 60 // = 55.99...
$minutes = round($minutes); // round 55.9999 up to 56
$hours = $parts[0];

echo "$hours hrs $minutes mins";
```

probably could be written a bit better but my excuse is I'm tired :)

That should give you an idea though and let you do what you need to.